# Exclude Control from Page.Isvalid

Tags: asp.net

I have a few controls on a page that are all in the same validation group.  Depending on certain conditions, one of these controls can be set to visible=false (and the user wont be able to input anything into it).  If this happens, is there a way to remove said control from the validation group?  Code like this:

```
if(testControl.Visible==false) testControl.ValidationGroup="";
```

does nothing.  Yet, if I remove the validationgroup from the aspx page like so:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="testControl" runat="server" validationgroup=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The page will validate.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Just a suggestion, does setting it to Visible="false" do anything?

Comment: yes it does.  When set to false the control doesn't show up on the page

Comment: Yeah but it also doesn't validate?

Comment: There's an error in the code you posted: it's not visable, it's visible.

Comment: whoops.  Typo on my part.  This isn't the auctual code my project is using.

Comment: Shouldn't your RequiredFieldValidator have a property ControlToValidate="testControl" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is being hit in the code-behind file? I mean, your control is really invisible when you check that condition?

```
if(testControl.Visible == false)
   testControl.ValidationGroup = string.Empty;
```

Put a breakpoint in `testControl.ValidationGroup="";` and see if the debugger stops there.

Where is the code above? It should be inside the PageLoad method for example.

Call `Page.Validate("NameOfYourValidationGroup")` after that code.

What is the problem here I think:

You're setting this `testControl` with `Visible = False` and then you post back to the server. When you do `testControl.ValidationGroup = string.Empty` it'll have no effect because it has already posted back to the server:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.validationgroup.aspx):

> TextBox..::.ValidationGroup Property
>
> Gets or sets the group of controls for
>   which the TextBox control causes
>   validation when it posts back to the
>   server.

This way you should call this code `testControl.ValidationGroup = string.Empty;` when you hide your control setting it to `Visible = false` so that when the page loads again for the user the control won't be assigned to that ValidationGroup. Now, if you postback the page it should validate the way you want it.

Set `testControl.CausesValidation = false` too.

Comment: Tried it.  The debugger does go over testControl.ValidationGroup=""; hence my confusion

Comment: At the moment, a random function.  However I have tried it in both init and page load....no success

Comment: Are you sure you're not assigning a validation group to that control at a later time in the code?

Comment: Its not assigned anywhere else (at least that I can find).  Going to try prerender now

Comment: Just to be sure: when you put that code in the PageLoad method the debugger stops there? Your control is Visible == false?

Comment: Prerender didn't work either :(

Yes it did stop there and was visible==false

Comment: Remember that you should put that code in the PageLoad method before the if (Page.IsValid) assertion...

Comment: Definitely did that.  At this point I think it might be better to write my own validation code if the control is hidden.  Thank you for your help though, it is appreciated :)

Comment: Try to call the Validate method for that group after that code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validate%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Still didn't work (compile error).  I dont know if its good form to mark an answer as complete when its not, but if you want points for it its yours.

Comment: No... I don't mind. I'd like to help you get this thing working.

Comment: Heh, me too.  Writing my own validation seems to have worked, but if we can get it to work the proper way, all the better

Comment: Did you understand what I wrote in my answer? When you check for Page.IsValid it won't consider `testControl.ValidationGroup = string.Empty;` because the validation was done when the page was posted back to the server. At that time the control still was part of that ValidationGroup.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, but it still didn't work  Guess I am going to have to stick with if(Page.IsValid || myOwnSetOfConditions)

Comment: When do you set testControl.Visible = false?

Comment: Shouldn't you set it to Visible = false depending on some condition as you describe in your question? Shouldn't it be during runtime?

Comment: whoops.  Misread that as testControl.causesValidation.
Visible is set as false in a helper function.  The Order is, Init, helperFunction, Page_Load

Comment: Try to put this code `testControl.ValidationGroup = string.Empty;`
 in that helper method and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help?:

```
testControl.IsValid = true;
```

Use for ex. with:

```
Page.Validate();
// manual override of specific control
testControl.IsValid = true;

// Guard
if (! Page.IsValid) return; // Or do own custom logic
// else
// Do your stuff here...
```